sub-component does not display the Angular Material design of the containing component
I have a component that uses Angular Material components and its design works great.
But within this component there is another component that is defined as standalone:false and it also uses the same components of Angular Material, but its design simply does not work - that is, it does not cause a compilation error but simply does not refer to the design of Angular Material.
It shouldn't be a problem in imports because in the wrapping component the design works great.
I tried to add encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None to the external component
And it didn't help
Here is the attached code:
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from '../../Models/Customer';
import { customerService } from '../../services/costumer.service';
import { MaterialModule } from '../../material/material.module';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
@Component({
  selector: 'customer-list',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MaterialModule, CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './customer-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-list.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class CustomerListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  displayedColumns = ['first_Name', 'last_Name', 'address', 'phone', 'email', ' '];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Customer> = new MatTableDataSource<Customer>();
  private customersSubscription?: Subscription;

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private customerService: customerService, private router: Router, public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadCustomers();
  }

  loadCustomers(): void {
    this.customersSubscription = this.customerService.customers$.subscribe({
      next: customers => {
        this.dataSource.data = customers;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      },
      error: error => {
        console.error('Error loading customers:', error);
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.customersSubscription) {
      this.customersSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }

  addCustomer(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/customer-details', -1]);
  }

  editCustomer(selected: Customer): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/customer-details', selected.id]);
  }

  deleteCustomer(customer: Customer): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialog);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.customerService.deleteCustomer(customer.id!).subscribe({
          next: () => {
            console.log('Customer deleted successfully');
          },
          error: error => {
            console.error('Error deleting customer:', error);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}

/*-------------------------confirm-dialog-component----------------------------------------- */

@Component({
  selector: 'confirm-dialog',
  template: `
    <div >
      <h1 mat-dialog-title>Confirm Deletion</h1>
      <div mat-dialog-content>Are you sure you want to delete this client?</div>
      <div mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()" >No</button>
        <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="onYesClick()" cdkFocusInitial>Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ConfirmDialog  {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmDialog>) {}

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close(false);
  }

  onYesClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close(true);
  }
}


I would really appreciate any hint as to what the problem could be

The dialog is opened in the root of the application and has no relation to the component that opens it, styles wise and import. So it's better for the dialog component to have its own imports and styles. We can also set it as standalone, since it works independently of any other component.
@Component({
  selector: 'confirm-dialog',
  standalone: true,
  styles: [``],
  imports: [MaterialModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div >
      <h1 mat-dialog-title>Confirm Deletion</h1>
      <div mat-dialog-content>Are you sure you want to delete this client?</div>
      <div mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()" >No</button>
        <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="onYesClick()" cdkFocusInitial>Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ConfirmDialog  {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmDialog>) {}

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close(false);
  }

  onYesClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close(true);
  }
}


Wow thank you very much. That was really my problem.
But can you tell me why it didn't work that way? In principle, it was supposed to recognize the import of the external component. I'm wrong?

@AgotaKristof When you create using createComponent, it does not recognize the imports of parent components, maybe the module level imports are recognized, for simplicity, I just used standalone and added the necessary imports. The imports in the parent module are shared to all components in delcarations, since we create this component dynamically using material, the imports might not be recognized

Thanks for the explanation!! You really made me wise!
